# Pandas: flag consecutive values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series of the form `[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 , 0 , 1].`

```
0: indicates economic increase.
1: indicates economic decline.
```

A recession is signaled by two consecutive declines (1).

The end of the recession is signaled by two consecutive increase (0).

In the above dataset I have two recessions, begin at index 3, end at index 5 and begin at index 8 end at index 11.

I am at a lost for how to approach this with pandas.  I would like to identify the index for the start and end of the recession.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Here is my python attempt at a soln.

```
np_decline =  np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 , 0 , 1])
recession_start_flag = 0
recession_end_flag = 0
recession_start = []
recession_end = []

for i in range(len(np_decline) - 1):
    if recession_start_flag == 0 and np_decline[i] == 1 and np_decline[i + 1] == 1:
        recession_start.append(i)
        recession_start_flag = 1
    if recession_start_flag == 1 and np_decline[i] == 0 and np_decline[i + 1] == 0:
        recession_end.append(i - 1)
        recession_start_flag = 0

print(recession_start)
print(recession_end)
```

Is the a more pandas centric approach?
Leon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The start of a run of 1's satisfies the condition

```
x_prev = x.shift(1)
x_next = x.shift(-1)
((x_prev != 1) & (x == 1) & (x_next == 1))
```

That is to say, the value at the start of a run is 1 and the previous value is not 1 and the next value is 1. Similarly, the end of a run satisfies the condition

```
((x == 1) & (x_next == 0) & (x_next2 == 0))
```

since the value at the end of a run is 1 and the next two values value are 0.
We can find indices where these conditions are true using `np.flatnonzero`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 , 0 , 1])
x_prev = x.shift(1)
x_next = x.shift(-1)
x_next2 = x.shift(-2)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(start = np.flatnonzero((x_prev != 1) & (x == 1) & (x_next == 1)),
         end = np.flatnonzero((x == 1) & (x_next == 0) & (x_next2 == 0))))
print(df[['start', 'end']])
```

yields

```
   start  end
0      3    5
1      8   11
```

Comment: have bug。  if data is [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 , 0 ,1, 0 , 0 , 1]

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 , 0 , 1], columns=['signal'])
df_prev = df.shift(1)['signal']
df_next = df.shift(-1)['signal']
df_next2 = df.shift(-2)['signal']
df.loc[(df_prev != 1) & (df['signal'] == 1) & (df_next == 1), 'start'] = 1
df.loc[(df['signal'] != 0) & (df_next == 0) & (df_next2 == 0), 'end'] = 1
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df = df.astype(int)

    signal  start  end
0        0      0    0
1        1      0    0
2        0      0    0
3        1      1    0
4        1      0    0
5        1      0    1
6        0      0    0
7        0      0    0
8        1      1    0
9        1      0    0
10       0      0    0
11       1      0    1
12       0      0    0
13       0      0    0
14       1      0    0
```

Comment: perhaps just `.fillna` with 0 to make it neat and tidy.

Answer (score 6):

use `rolling(2)`

```
s = pd.Series([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 , 0 , 1])
```

I subtract `.5` so the `rolling` sum is `1` when a recession starts and `-1` when it stops.

```
s2 = s.sub(.5).rolling(2).sum()
```

since both `1` and `-1` evaluate to `True` I can mask the rolling signal to just start and stops and `ffill`.  Get truth values of when they are positive or negative with `gt(0)`.

```
pd.concat([s, s2.mask(~s2.astype(bool)).ffill().gt(0)], axis=1, keys=['signal', 'isRec'])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @piRSquared. How could I amend what you have done over two columns Recession Start and Recession End. Where Recession Start will be True if its a Recession Start else False and of course Recession End would be if the Recession has Ended True else False.

Answer (score 6):

Similar idea using `shift`, but writing the result as a single Boolean column:

```
# Boolean indexers for recession start and stops.
rec_start = (df['signal'] == 1) & (df['signal'].shift(-1) == 1)
rec_end = (df['signal'] == 0) & (df['signal'].shift(-1) == 0)

# Mark the recession start/stops as True/False.
df.loc[rec_start, 'recession'] = True
df.loc[rec_end, 'recession'] = False

# Forward fill the recession column with the last known Boolean.
# Fill any NaN's as False (i.e. locations before the first start/stop).
df['recession'] = df['recession'].ffill().fillna(False)
```

The resulting output:

```
    signal recession
0        0     False
1        1     False
2        0     False
3        1      True
4        1      True
5        1      True
6        0     False
7        0     False
8        1      True
9        1      True
10       0      True
11       1      True
12       0     False
13       0     False
14       1     False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use scipy.signal.find_peaks for this problem.

```
    from scipy.signal import find_peaks

    np_decline =  np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 , 0 , 1])
    peaks = find_peaks(np_decline,width=2)
    recession_start_loc =  peaks[1]['left_bases'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function2(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    if dd.iat[0,1]>=2:
        if dd.query("col1==0").pipe(len)==1:
            return (dd.index.min(),dd.index.max()+1)
        else:
            dd1=dd.query("col1==1")
            return (dd1.index.min(),dd1.index.max())

col2=df1.col1.diff().eq(1).cumsum()
df1.groupby(col2).apply(lambda dd:dd.assign(col3=dd.col1.cumprod().sum()))\
    .groupby('col3',sort=False).apply(function2).dropna()
```

out:

```
   col3
3     (3, 5)
2    (8, 11)
dtype: object
```